# Is there a way to disable the new feature in grub2 where it collapses all your old kernels?

Tags: grub2

For example if I have more than one linux kernel I like to boot and I maintain my own /boot properly...I don't want the list collapsed.  I want to choose the appropriate installation(one for opencl, one for wireless stuff, one for common usage, one for anonymity, etc).

Comment: I'm not sure about where to find it in /etc/default/grub etc but if you look at the actual /boot/grub/grub.cfg it will have entries starting with submenu.  I guess you just remove that line and leave the regular menuentry etc.

Comment: thx.  i'm looking at playing with 41_custom instead of removing the submenu since it seems to scale/last through updates.  i'll take a look at that though

Comment: I have just seen submenu entries in /etc/grub.d/10_linux.  might be worth a look/play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit `/etc/default/grub`

```
# graphical
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

# command line
sudo -e /etc/default/grub
```

Comment out the HIDDEN_MENU option

```
# change the time out to something other then 0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=20

# comment out #GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=3
```

Update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

For additional information on grub see [Ubuntu wiki grub 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)

Comment: ty, i gave it the check since it is exactly what i asked for.  does this persist through a grub update?

Comment: yes it will persist

Comment: I thought you wanted the list to show all kernels in 1 long list and not submenu.  Sorry, if I'd known all you wanted was to just show the list at all.

Comment: thx again @bodhi.zazen

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work for me. I see exactly the same menu as before...