# How can I show all kernels in the Grub2 menu, ie disable submenu ("Previous Linux Versions")?

Tags: boot, grub2

Is there an easy way to disable Grub2 new `submenu` structure? I'd like to have back the old structure (each option as a `menuentry`) where each kernel is visible and selectable on the fly.

I've already tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90463/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-new-feature-in-grub2-where-it-collapses-all-your-o) solution, to no avail. And [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com/msg13394.html) is the most promising solution I've found until now. I didn't try it (I'll test it tomorrow) but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the latest Ubuntu (14.04), one can specify:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y
```

in `/etc/default/grub`.

Then apply with

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Confirmed (=y) working on Trusty 14.04.1 with 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1, GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true does not work! love how consistent config is...

Comment: Just tried this parameter and it worked exactly as expected. I noticed you used "=true" instead of "=y". Maybe that's why it is not working for you, as grub's manual states you should use "=y". See "info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'" for mor information. My environment, for reference: $ uname -a = "Linux ruapehu 3.19.0-51-generic #58~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 22:02:58 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"; $ cat /etc/issue = "Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS \n \l"
`

Comment: Confirmed (=y) working on 21.04 with grub 2.04-1ubuntu45

Answer (score 5):

> #### Deprecated
>
> The answer below applies to Ubuntu versions older than 14.04

```
gksu gedit /etc/grub.d/10_linux
```

At the end of the file:

```
  if [ "$list" ] && ! $in_submenu; then
    echo "submenu \"Previous Linux versions\" {"
    in_submenu=:
  fi
done

if $in_submenu; then
  echo "}"
```

add the "#" character in front of some lines to disable (i.e. comment out) their effect, make it look like this (4 lines changed):

```
  if [ "$list" ] && ! $in_submenu; then
    #echo "submenu \"Previous Linux versions\" {"
    in_submenu=:
  fi
done

#if $in_submenu; then
  #echo "}"
#fi
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes.

Comment: See Nish Aravamudan answer here in this page which is the right one for Trusty (GRUB 2.02)

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you don't mind adding a `PPA` then yes!

**[Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer):**

Grub Customizer is a graphical interface to configure the grub2/burg settings.It allows you to edit the GRUB2 menu entries: reorder, rename or add/remove entries.

**Installation:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

**How to disable Grub2 submenu?**

Once installed, Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `grub-customizer` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Select the submenu entries one by one and click on **↑**(Up) button in toolbar to move them to main menu. 
[image]

And no more submenu! Save your settings by clicking on save button in toolbar. That's it!
[image]

---

*To remove Grub Customizer run following commands in terminal*

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge grub-customizer
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Nice, I'll give it a try. However, what I'm really looking for is something that doesn't need to be re-applied at each kernel update (or at least that can be re-applied automatically). Is there a way to "script" `Grub Customizer`?

Comment: I don't think so you'll have to reapply it upon every kernel update, it will automatically create new entries under main menu. Note the two entries in Linux menu `(new Entries)` and `(new Entries of Previous Linux versions)`.

Comment: No need for a PPA since Trusty/GRUB2.02: see Nish Aravamudan answer here in this page which is the right one since.