# How can I disable "Previous Linux Version" entries in the Grub menu

Tags: grub2, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I show all kernels in the Grub2 menu, ie disable submenu (“Previous Linux Versions”)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143862/how-can-i-show-all-kernels-in-the-grub2-menu-ie-disable-submenu-previous-linu)

I know that, most of the user liked the new grub2 feature of hiding old kernel entries in the menu item "Previous Linux Version". But, I don't want to go to that menu for booting a previous kernel version. My question is "How can I disable this feature"? i.e, "How can I force grub2 to include all kernel version entries in the menu?"